# Analogue signal generation: Which is better Standalone or PWM DAC?

Tags: analog, pwm, dac, sine

Most controller/processor come with PWM output and integrated standalone DAC module....

My need is to generate 50/60Hz analog signal for testing purpose! Which would be the good choice PWM DAC or Standalone DAC?

Better in terms of:
* Simple electronics
* Simple coding
* Quality signals (lesser distortion)
* Sine wave generation

Comment: What do you define as "better"? Not all DACs are the same. Many high performance "standalone" sigma-delta DACs actually generate a (sort of) PWM signal. Also a *50/60Hz analog signal* means little, a 50 Hz signal can have very different requirements depending on shape of the signal and its bandwidth.

Comment: Sine or square wave?

Comment: Better in terms of:
* Simple electronics
* Simple coding
* Quality signals
* Sine wave generation

Comment: Do you *only* care about generating pure sine tones, or more complicated waveforms should be supported?

Answer (score 1):

Given the MCU_PWM_DAC has electro-static-discharge protection diodes on the (inputs and) outputs of the MCU, your signal will always have MCU_CLOCK and MCU_program_related spikes and trash that are non-random.

Use this filter on the "DAC"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fATxfI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like this approach. If parts allow, the filter corner can be made a little sharper (less overdamped) by keeping the RC of each section constant. In principle for this example 1k/10u , 3k3/3u3 , 10k/1u  ... this is prob more reasonable with higher freq filter (a bit smaller caps)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that a Sinewave output is required here.

Any primitive DAC you implement will work fine but will likely be noisy unless a fair bit of design is carried out to filter it etc.

All things considered the PWM DAC you implement yourself is likely to be much noisier than a standalone one - purely for the reason that it has been optimized for a particular usage / price point. On the other hand a PWM one will likely be cheaper and easier to get working - because you will not need to figure out the comms and configuration registers of the external DAC.

**So for simple I would go with the PWM option - but for better quality I would use the external DAC.**

Actually if it's just the signal that is of interest, I would just use a computer with sound card to generate the signals if that is an option. You should get a very clean signal at these frequencies with 16-24bits of resolution.